# How to call custom hook inside of form submit button?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am create custom hook that fetch requests network.I want to call custom hook when form submit button clicked but depending on hook rules i can't do that. how to can implement this scenario?

this custom hook:

```
const useRequest = (url, method, dependencies, data = null) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await request[method](url, data);
        setResponse(res);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (e) {
        setError(e);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, dependencies);
  return { response, error, loading };
};
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your attempt to rework this to work with a form onSubmit event handler, and include any debugging details, issue specifics, and actual and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Move fetchData function out of useEffect and export it:

```
const useRequest = (url, method, dependencies, data = null) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await request[method](url, data);
        setResponse(res);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (e) {
        setError(e);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
  useEffect(() => {

    fetchData();
  }, dependencies);
  return { response, error, loading, fetchData };
};
```

Than when you can call it anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks this is a great idea but how to prevent from calling it on mount component ? if we have empty dependency array